# Creating a sequence manually in BerkeleyDB JE

Tags: java, database, sequence, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I want to create a sequence in BerkeleyDB, that I can operate manually, but I don't know how to do this. I would like to have something similar to an SQL sequence object. I have found a class in the API docs, but it's unclear how to create one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works fine:

```
@Test
public void testSequenceCreation() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    EnvironmentConfig econf = EnvironmentConfig.DEFAULT.setAllowCreate(true);
    Environment env = new Environment(envHome, econf);

    StoreConfig sconf = StoreConfig.DEFAULT.setAllowCreate(true);
    EntityStore store = new EntityStore(env, "TestStore", sconf);

    store.setPrimaryConfig(FakeEntity.class, 
            DatabaseConfig.DEFAULT.setAllowCreate(true));
    store.setSequenceConfig("testSequence", SequenceConfig.DEFAULT.setAllowCreate(true));

    Sequence seq = store.getSequence("testSequence");
    Assert.assertEquals(0, seq.get(null, 1));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, seq.get(null, 1));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, seq.get(null, 1));

    store.sync();

    seq.close();
    store.close();
    env.close();        
}
```

All I had to do is set a configuration, and the sequence was created.